# Login to website with Python requests

Tags: python, authentication, web, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am having some trouble logging into this website: https://illinoisjoblink.illinois.gov/ada/r/home

I am able to submit the payload, but I get redirected to a page claiming a bookmark error. Here is the code and relevant error messages. I'm not sure how to proceed. I appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

```python
    session = requests.Session()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(SEARCH_URL).content, "html.parser")
    inputs = soup.find_all('input')
    token = ''
    for t in inputs:
        try:
            if t['name'] == 'authenticity_token':
                token = t['value']
                break
        except KeyError as e:
            pass
    login_data = dict(v_username=USER_NAME,
                      v_password=PASSWORD,
                      authenticity_token=token,
                      commit='Log In')
    login_data['utf-8'] = '&#x2713;'

    r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data)

    print(r.content)
```

`Bookmark Error <b>You may be seeing this error as a result of bookmarking this page. Unfortunately, our site design will not allow the bookmarking of most internal pages.</b> If you wish to contact the system administra
tor concerning this error, you may send an email to <a href="mailto:DES.IJLSysAdmSpprt@illinois.gov">DES.IJLSysAdmSpprt@illinois.gov</a>. Please reference error number <b>646389</b>.<p>Thank you for your patience.<br><br> Hit your browser back button to return to the previous page.`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `login_data` parameters are wrong? When I inspect the POST for logging in, the necessary parameters appear to be: `v_username`, `v_password`, `FormName`, `fromlogin`, and maybe most importantly, `button`. I would suggest you add all these parameters to your `login_data` dictionary. Your dictionary would look something like:

```
login_data = {'v_username': USER_NAME,
              'v_password': PASSWORD,
              'authenticity_token': token,
              'FormName': 0,
              'fromlogin': 1,
              'button': 'Log+in'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I included these parameters in my dictionary but it did not seem to help. However, when I get rid of `login_data['utf-8'] = '&#x2713;` the login does not work at all and I get redirected to the original login page. Also, when I inspected the POST for logging in, I didn't see where `FormName`, `fromlogin`, and `button` were.